# What is this number type?

Tags: javascript

What is this number type?

```
console.log(0100); // output 64
console.log(050); // output 40
console.log(010); // output 8
```

Hexadecimal would:

```
0100 = 256
050 = 80
010 = 16
```

Comment: That's octal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates _"Note that decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by another decimal digit, but If the next digit after the leading 0 is smaller than 8, the number gets parsed as an octal number."_

Comment: C'mon. If `8` is represented as `10`, what system could it be?

Comment: "8 is represented as 010". Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [octal numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers) a.k.a base 8.

You should avoid using that syntax since it is not allowed in strict mode.

You can, however, [use them in ES6/ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals) with some modified syntax.

```
0o100; // 64
0o50;  // 40
0o10;  // 8
```

Comment: Thanks. The staff did not like the question. ^ ^

Comment: @Gurigraphics It's not the staff. It's just users. I don't think it deserves *this* much hate but it is one of those "if you think about it for a second, you'll figure it out" kind of questions.

Comment: Should be it. I thought the question was poorly worded.